# Image grid display like Facebook

Tags: jquery, css, html, image-processing, image-gallery

What logic Facebook use to display grid of images on timeline, like it depends on number of images or resolution of total images. I need to implement something like that, right now I am implementing it based on number of images, Is I am doing right ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

did you check this jQuery plugin ? 
http://www.jqueryrain.com/2015/03/facebook-album-browser-jquery/

[image]